# In glibc <= 2.23, why is `0;` used in mutex_lock macro?

Tags: c, malloc, c-preprocessor, glibc

[For glibc <= 2.23](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.23/source/sysdeps/generic/malloc-machine.h), it looks like the generic definition of malloc's `mutex_lock` macro uses an `int` as a mutex. `1` means in use, and `0` means free.

It defines this generic set of macros:

```c
typedef int mutex_t
# define mutex_init(m)          (*(m) = 0)
# define mutex_lock(m)          ({ *(m) = 1; 0; })
# define mutex_trylock(m)       (*(m) ? 1 : ((*(m) = 1), 0))
# define mutex_unlock(m)        (*(m) = 0)
```

For `mutex_lock(m)`, what purpose does `0;` serve?

Comment: Perhaps it's documented as returning `0` on success?

Comment: `0;` is a statement with no side effects though. It doesn't set a return value.

Comment: If you read [the GCC statement expression documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) you will see that "The last thing in the compound statement should be an expression followed by a semicolon; the value of this subexpression serves as the value of the entire construct." In short, it will act as a return value.

Comment: Ah neat! Learned something new. So if `0;` was not there, the return value would have been 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `({ *(m) = 1; 0; })` is a GCC extension to standard C, and it's called a [*statement expression*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html). It allows you to have multiple arbitrary statements inside an expression.

But all non-void expressions must result in a value, and for statement expressions

> [t]he last thing in the compound statement should be an expression followed by a semicolon; the value of this subexpression serves as the value of the entire construct

So the last `0;` is simply the result of the expression.